# Trying to output final DOM result

Tags: php, dom

I have search the entire internet, what I have found is getting values of tags with attributes. But I have a tag to extract contents, the tag has no attributes. The tag is `cite`.

Here is my tag:

```
<div>
    <cite>My name is Jimmy</cite>
    <cite>My name is Paul</cite>
    <cite>I am Sarah</cite>
</div>
```

And here is my DOM call:

```
$dom = new domDocument; 

/*** load the html into the object ***/ 
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

/*** discard white space ***/ 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

/*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cite'); 

/*** loop over the table rows ***/ 
foreach ($tables as $row) {
    /*** get each column by tag name ***/ 
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('cite'); 

    /*** echo the values ***/ 
    echo $cols->textContent.'<br />'; 
}
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: `DOMNodeList::$textContent`

What I would like to get is this:

> My name is Jimmy
>   My name is Paul
>   I am Sarah

Please guys I need help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried any simple debugging, like checking that `$row` is what you think it is and also `$cols` ?? A simple `print_r($var_i_am_interested_in);` should tell you lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

```
$html = "<div>
<cite>My name is Jimmy</cite>
<cite>My name is Paul</cite>
<cite>I am Sarah</cite>
</div>";

$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$cities = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cite');
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    echo $city->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Zualex -  you made it really simple for me. You guys rock! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You currently trying to get the tag cite inside each tag cite. Simply remove the second `getElementsByTagName` in your loop.

```
foreach ($tables as $row) {
    echo $row->textContent.'<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's an oversight! Philipp thanks. It works perfectly!